# Best way to use a List<T> in a Key/Value collection?

Tags: .net, .net-3.5, collections, dictionary

What's the best way to keep a collection-object (List in example) in a Key/Value situation, where the key is a ID and the value is a collection of a type T?

Is this the only option or is there a better solution/another collection for this in .NET 3.5?

```
var x = new Dictionary<int, List<type>>();
```

Comment: You mean var x = new Dictionary<int, List<T>>(); ?

Comment: The question is a bit unclear, could you please rephrase it? Are you asking if Dictionary is a good collection for holding keys and values?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a good solution and will work quite well - you are effectively using a dictionary object of { key = int, value = 4 byte reference }.

When you retrieve a value by the key you will get back the reference to the `List<T>` on the heap and be able to use it.  This will be a very efficent and compact solution to your apparent problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea if this is what you need but I'll have chop at it.

```
public Dictionary<int,List<T>> myFunction<T>()
{
    var returnvalue = new Dictionary<int,List<T>>();
    //Do some stuff with the collection.
    return returnvalue;
}
```

which you can then call

```
public void Main()
{
  var functionreturn = myFunction<String>();
}
```

I'm not sure if this will help you or not but it may help you reword your question.

NOTE: The above is air code and is untested.

Comment: -1 for air code.  Better to test then post than to provide something quickly.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is anything within the framework, but I think there is a  MultiDictionary collection in the PowerCollections library. You could try that.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should probably write your wrapper class according to your needs. I mean, if you need to store a dictionary of pre-made lists, `Dictionary<int, List<type>>` should be fine as long as it's only a private property. You should not expose it though publicly as obviously it exposes too much information and you cannot cast it to `IDictionary<int, IList<T>>` or something similar because of the lack of covariance.

Your best bet would be something like that:

```
class MyWrapper<T>()
{
    private Dictionary<int, List<T>> dictionary { get; set; }
    public MyWrapper() { dictionary = new Dictionary<int, List<T>>(); }

    // Adds a new item to the collection
    public void Add(int key, T item)
    {
       List<T> list = null;
       if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list))
       {
          // If dictionary does not contain the key, we need to create a new list
          list = new List<T>();
          dictionary.Add(key, list);
       }
       list.Add(item);
    }

    public IEnumerable<T> this[int key]     
    {
       get
       {
           List<T> list = null;
           // We just return an empty list if the key is not found
           if (!dictionary.TryGetValue(key, out list)) return new List<T>();
           else return list;
       }
    }
}
```

Obviously, your needs might be different, you might need to implement a couple of interfaces, etc., but this is the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

If your ID is a member of your type, you might consider implementing a [`System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection<TKey, TItem>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132438.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you are looking for a multi-valued dictionary, i.e. a keyed collection, where each key can have multiple values? [PowerCollections](http://www.codeplex.com/PowerCollections) has such a MultiDictionary.